# How to set up Ubuntu + Win 8 in virtualbox, when Win 8 is pre-installed?

Tags: installation, windows, virtualbox, windows-8

I have a Samsung i3 Ultrabook. It runs Windows 8. I used to run Ubuntu in Virtualbox. I hate it. I want to run Ubuntu as host. But Win 8 should be running in Virtualbox (for Office + Acrobat). But the notebook does not come with a Win 8 CD or serial number or anything. I fear that once I install Ubuntu as a host, I won't be able to get a running Win 8 again. Win 8 seems to be backed up on a recovery partition, but not on a physical drive.

How to set this up?

No, I don't want a dual boot, I want Ubuntu only. With Win 8 running in virtualbox.

No, there is no Win 8 DVD that comes with the ultrabook

Comment: 1st make a live usb of ubuntu 13.04 and check that every thing is working ....touchpad, screen brightness etc...

Comment: have you tested Ubuntu in Vmware workstation 9  ... it run very cool on windows 8 host

Answer (score 3):

First, I'd like to know where the "Windows 8 Installation Media" is.  If its a separate DVD you are golden.  If it's on a "Recovery Partition" it's going to be harder.

The problem is that Windows 8 installs to the Hardware.  It *ONLY* has drivers for the exact hardware it's on.  If you were to try to migrate the partition into a Virtual Disk Image, it would not boot, as the hardware is different.

Ubuntu 13.04 will run perfectly on the Samsung Ultrabook, and Windows 8 runs fine inside of VirtualBox.  It's *getting* Windows 8 into the VDI that poses the problem.

BTW... I hope it's more than just Office and Acrobat that you need Windows for, because these both run very well under Ubuntu 13.04 (PlayonLinux install of WINE).

Comment: No, there is no DVD. It seems to be a recovery partition. I don't need the exact copy of my current installation, I am totally fine with a vanilla Win 8 running inside my Ubuntu system. And, well, I also need Photoshop, Illustrator, InDesign and neither of these seems to work fine with PlayOnLinux). I also need Silverlight, so I need a Win machine running somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

@Karen: Martin has asked for Windows 8. The link you have provided is for Windows 7. This makes a lot of difference since Windows 8 runs on UEFI with Secure Boot (and not with a BIOS)

@Martin: I am trying the same thing as you...
My experience so far with Virtual Box 4.2.10:

1. Secure Boot: 
   Your host system (ubuntu) needs to run with Secure Boot "disabled". VirtualBox acts as a kernel module. Secure boot allows only kernel modules that have been "certified" with the Secure Boot key. VirtualBox is not certified and therefore will not run with Secure Boot "enabled".
2. Windows  8 OEM Installation Medium:
   I have on my HP Envy 23 with preinstalled Windows 8 OEM and on my HP Envy 4 with preinstalled Windows 8 OEM an option to start "HP Tools" and then be able to generate a installation media (be careful: You can only generate only one such a media). Unfortunately I have chosen to generate an USB-stick. VirtualBox does not support boot from USB yet. Therefore make sure to generate a DVD.
3. Windows 8 OEM License:
   As I read the OEM license you are allowed to run one single Windows 8 on the hardware. It does not matter if this is as host or as guest. So this should be fine for you. However as Windows 8 checks the hardware you need to be sure not to change the parameters of you virtual hardware. Otherwise you will probably have to phone Microsoft again to get a new key.

I am very interested if you succeed. Please let me know. Good luck!

I have also tried with VMWare Player 5.0.2 . But I also did not succeed

Comment: please add your comments to karen and martin as comments on their answer / question. Those comments has nothing to do with the solution to the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I researched this for ages. My solution came from here. http://blog.c22.cc/2013/05/19/quickpost-windows-8-digital-product-key-recovery/

Comment: While this may in theory answer the question (or a portion of the question), it's better to include a summary of the solution here (along with the source link) rather than just the link.

Answer (score 0):

Stop worrying, all concerns already solved by others to accomplish exactly as you hope:

https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=31759&start=30

The big considerations are exporting and testing your Samsung's SLIC bin, someone else incorrectly asserted Windows 8 only includes drivers for the included hardware and it is the opposite since Windows installation media grows because of all the legacy hardware support that is one of the few reasons Windows is attractive for wide range of hardware support.

Windows virtual driver support isn't an issue whether ancient versions of vMWare or cranky Hyper-v, the devices are always more generic and never a problem for Windows Plug n' Play / hardware AutoDetect.

You can extract your existing Windows Serial Number with lots of things like Nirsoft Produkey that is a single file executable, no installation and free at Nirsoft.net. You'll probably need it at first run of virtualized 8 that will scream about new hardware and demand a re-entry but not an issue.

Regarding your concern about resorting to old 8 once Ubuntu is installed,  you already know that imaging is the better way to freeze dry your currently running Win8, but advanced format drives makes is harder if still using a Binary Research copy of Ghost 2 from the floppy,  Macrium Reflect free edition seems capable of working with most AF drives even when Paragon or Acronis chokes, try it to verify it images your entire HDD.

Comment: this links to windows 7. The question is about windows 8, which has a completely different boot structure.

Answer (score 0):

My wife won't let me drop Win 8 on our machine, so I've been running Ubuntu in VMWare. It works ok, but would run better on a fresh install.. I don't use much more than a browser and some light media, so it's ok for now, until I can afford a laptop of my own to wipe and use Linux only. I want a dual boot of Ubuntu and Mint, and I'll be a happy camper.. Now, I have Ubuntu, Mint, OpenSuse, and Linux Royal all on VM's..

But like mentioned above, to do what you want, you first need to create your recovery media. I recommend Belarc Advisor to get your product key. It'll find any and all product keys and even registration #'s on your internal components.. Great software.

Then do a clean install of Ubuntu, create your VM for Win8, and have at it..